# Does definite integration invalidate equalities?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given any old equation, say
$$x^2+x+a=0$$

Rearranging and raising by $e$
$$e^{-x^2}=e^{x+a}$$

Integrating both sides w.r.t. x over the domain $[-\infty, \infty]$ gives

$$\sqrt{\pi} = e^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x\:dx$$

But this cannot be true since the RHS diverges. Why is the equation no longer valid after integration? Differentiation preserves equalities. Why does it seem that differentiation's inverse operation not preserve equality?

Comment: Equation is not a function. You can only integrate a function but not an equation.

Comment: Those are two very different things.  The first equation is only valid for a single value of $x$.  Thus the integral "equation," which involves all other values of $x$, is invalid.

Comment: Differentiation does not preserve equalities. $x^2+x+a=0$ does not imply that $2x+1=0$ !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is $a$?

$\bullet$ A fixed constant?  Then $x^2+x+a=0$ is satisfied by only (at most) two values $x$.  So it makes no sense to integrate over $x$.

$\bullet$ A function of $x$, defined implicitly by $x^2+x+a$?  Then you can integrate, but
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{x+a}x\;dx \ne e^{a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^x\:dx
$$
because $a$ is a function of $x$ and cannot be factored out.

Comment: Did you mean $e^{-a}$ in you second point. And it doesn't say $a$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: If $a$ is defined as $x^2 + x + a = 0$, then the value of $a$ depends on the value of $x$, so yes, $a$ is a function of $x$ whether or not you said so explicitly.

Comment: So that is means thinking about the equation as a circle in space with coordinates $x, a$. But then what would the integration mean.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have 
$$
f\stackrel{?}{=}g\implies \int_a^b f=\int_a^bg
$$
you need to have $f(x)=g(x)$ for almost every $x$ in $(a,b)$, i.e. except for a set of measure zero.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$x^2+x+a=0$$
Holds for a maximum of two real values of $x$, assuming $a$ is a constant. So if you say $$e^{-x^2}=e^{x+a}$$ 
This is true for at most two distinct values of x and integration over these values give $0$ since the thickness of the integration region is 0. So yes the integral holds and it is equal to 0. You can't integrate over entire real line as the two functions aren't equal over the entire real line.

Comment: Made a correction.